# Power Bi combine column and line chart with same table

Tags: powerbi

hoping someone can help this relatively new power bi user.

I have table similar to this:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIfuM.png)

I would like to chart A and B.  I would like A to be a line, and B to be a column.  I have been able to get them as columns, but the line sums the totals for each month.  I would just like a line for A and I would like B to be columns on the same chart.

Thanks for any input,

I have picke the line/column visual.  But I cannot seem to filter it correctly to acheive what I described.

Comment: Combining a line chart and a bart chart in a single graph is simple. There's a visual for it. The problem, I think, is with your data. The obvious is measure is SUM([Number])... but what's the other measure that you wanted to graph? If you put Month or Date on the x-axis, what other columns are left? you could do something like this with a dataset like (date, sale amount, sale cost) or something like that. Then you can create a "total amount" measure and a "sale cost" measure, and have one shown in the bar chart and the other in the line chart.

Answer (score 0):

Write custom columns for A and B in Power Query

```
A = if[#"Plan "] = "A" then [Number] else ""

B = if[#"Plan "] = "B" then [Number] else ""
```

Change the Data Types of A and B to decimal numbers.

Then use `Line and Clustered Column chart` to display A in bar chart and B in Line chart

[image]