# Power BI - Line and Clustered Column Chart

Tags: powerbi, visualization

How can I create Line & Clustered column chart in PBI while I have membership values in the same column for FY2022 and FY2023?
I wanna show the current fin-year values in Bar and the previous fin-year values in Line.
image attached
Thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4EBF.png)

Comment: two ways to solve your problem. one in PowerQuery, one with DAX. which one you prefer?

Comment: I answered similar question here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76638484/power-bi-combine-column-and-line-chart-with-same-table/76643939#76643939`